# sed find with a regex and replace does not work

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I created the following regex which works as I wish (see printscreen). Now my aim is to use that regex inside `sed` on Linux and replace each highlighted part (see printscreen) with the symbol `"`

[image]

So in a terminal I did:

```
sed 's/("{2,})/@/g' new.csv > output.csv
```

It does produce the file `output.csv` which is nevertheless identical to input.csv! I do not get an error message. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

**Input file [new.csv]**

```
"""lkadjsklsdjlkdasjklsafd""""
""alksdfkldsaf""
"lasdfkkldasj"
"""salfdjkdsafjfkdlj"""""
lkasjdfkldjaf lkasj fkladsf "aslkdjalksdfkfdls;"
lkasdjlkdfj lkasjd kldj flk ""alksdfkklj;"" alsdkfjlkdas
" "laksdjkldsfj" "   should delete nothing 
""laksdjkldsfj""     should delete
```

**Expected output file [output.csv]**

```
"lkadjsklsdjlkdasjklsafd"
"alksdfkldsaf"
"lasdfkkldasj"
"salfdjkdsafjfkdlj"
lkasjdfkldjaf lkasj fkladsf "aslkdjalksdfkfdls;"
lkasdjlkdfj lkasjd kldj flk alksdfkklj;" alsdkfjlkdas
" "laksdjkldsfj" "   should delete nothing 
"laksdjkldsfj"     should delete
```

Comment: `sed -E 's/"{2,}/@/g' new.csv > output.csv`

Comment: Wiktor, you are a superman. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you substitute with `@`? Don't you want `"`?

Comment: So, all you needed was to enable the POSIX ERE compatibility. It is a very well known issue.

Comment: Hello, benjamin, it's my mistake I updated @ to ". Actually what I want to replace is not really important. What is important is that I used a braket that I should not have use. Neverthless, I do not understand why I cannot use that braket. I expected regex to be 100% identical to what I use on https://regexr.com/

Comment: Ok Wiktor thanks a lot, so if I understand there is many kind of regex standards (I am actually not regex expert) I think I have to document myself on that topic...